# jquery wrapped CSS selectors differ for chrome and IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a jquery wrapped css selectors like`$($("#selector").find('input[type="textarea"])'`. I can put values to the input area in chrome through this`$($("#selector").find('input[type="textarea"]).val(someValue)'` but cannot possible through Internet explorer 11.

While inspecting in developer tool,
chrome is giving me

```
[ 

input style=​"float:​ left;​ width:​ 70px;​ height:​ 21px;​ margin:​ 4px 2px 4px 4px;​" autocomplete=​"off" type=​"textarea" id=​"jqxWidget15f259b7" class=​"jqx-widget jqx-widget-energyblue jqx-input jqx-input-energyblue jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-energyblue jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-energyblue"

]
```

but Internet explorer is giving me something different like an array of objects

`[object Object]{context: undefined, jquery: "2.1.1", length: 0, prevObject: Object {...}, selector: "input[t`ype=..."}

Is there any way that can I make a common jquery wrapper for inserting a value for the input textarea for both browsers?

Comment: in your code i think you have missed the single quote in following statement : `$($("#selector").find('input[type="textarea"]).val(someValue)`. It should be `$($("#selector").find('input[type="textarea"]').val(someValue)`. try adding single quote after closing square bracket.

Comment: No thats not the issue. The quote may be missed while I entered the jquery in the question. Its perfectly ok in Chrome but cant get anything in IE11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS is browser specific, so there's no way to make a common jquery wrapper. It's better to go browser specific. You can Change your Code like this,

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        if ($.browser.chrome)
        {
            **Your Logic for Chrome**
        }
        else {
            **IE logic**
        }
```

You may have to include JQUERY MIGRATE PLUGIN for this.

Comment: Thanks Navaneeth for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of IE11.  You should specify `text` instead of `textarea` in your HTML and JavaScript code.

INPUT element doesn't have `textarea` type.  If such invalid type is specified to `type` attribute, it's treated as default `text` type, and `type` property (not attribute) returns `text`.  IE's bug is to update `type` attribute value to `text` unnecessarily.